# Rails 4 and configuring Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

This has been asked many times before but I haven't found any solutions to my exact problem. I have a Rails 4 app and I have installed SideKiq to handle backgroud email processing. i have followed the basic instructions but keep getting a long error when I run

```
       bundle exec sidekiq
```

The main portion of the error is

```
    Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

This is pretty self-explanatory however it does appear to say in the documentation how to resolve this (unless I have misread). Clearly my set up wrong. I have tried adding a sidekiq.rb file with

```
   redis = { url: (ENV['REDIS_URL'] || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'), namespace: 'sidekiq' }

   Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
     config.redis = redis
   end

   Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
     config.redis = redis
   end
```

But no luck. Help wold be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is Redis actually running on port 6479?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm completely new to Redis  - how would I check this (I presume from the command line)

Comment: `redis-cli ping`. Are you sure you even installed redis? It seems the sidekiq docs assume you have redis running already. `brew install redis` if you are using HomeBrew, or check out the RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq

Comment: You are correct! Many thanks. I had assumed when I installed Sidekiq I got Redis as well. Obviously I am pretty new to this. Rails casts tutorial was fantastic just to get up and running. Make it and answer and I will mark you correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you even installed redis?

You can check with `redis-cli ping`.

It seems the Sidekiq docs assume you have Redis running already.

`brew install redis` if you are using HomeBrew, or check out the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).